# xamarin forms iOS bash script is missing in app center

Tags: bash, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

I have added appcenter-pre-build script in the xamarin forms android project, and it works well in the app center. However, when I added that same script to the xamarin forms iOS project, the script is not visible in the app center.

Does anyone know what could cause this issue?

Comment: Did you trigger another build? The sources need to be updated before the script is detected.

Comment: Well I have pushed the code to git, and it is configured to manual build in the app center. I have checked git and bash file is there. I have also just tried to manually build solution, but still script is not visible.

Comment: Naming is correct? And it is on the same level as the project/solution you are building?

Comment: in AppCenter, click the "Chat" icon and you'll be connected to someone on the engineering support team who can help you sort it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for comments, it turned out to be a configuration error in the app center. For some reason PM decided to change Project in build configuration from .iOS to shared, and I didn't noticed.

Sorry for wasting your time.